# Buttons not working when mobile header is fixed

Tags: css

I have given my site a fixed header by this css:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 520px) {
  .site-header {
    position: fixed!important;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
  }
}
```

I have added the z-index otherwise the buttons in my page overlaps the header instead of going under the header, but now the buttons are not working in mobile view. Here is the css for the buttons:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 520px) {
  .icon-box .icon-box-readmore {
    font-weight: 500;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #FFF;
    border-bottom: 0px;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-color: #FFA500;
    border-width: 2px;
    border-style: solid;
    font-size: 15px;
    padding-top: 7px;
    padding-bottom: 7px;
    padding-left: 50px;
    padding-right: 50px;
    letter-spacing: 4px;
    position: fixed;
    background-color: #FFA500;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 12px -3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
     z-index: 1;
  }
}
```

Please help to make buttons clickable in mobile view and at the same time make the site header sticky.

Comment: Can you include the relevant HTML?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is in the `.site-header` class, specifically the `height: 100%;`. Since you set the header to have `position: fixed`, having the height set to 100% will mean that the header takes the same height as the browser (effectively having an element over all your content, including the buttons).

You have a couple options to fix this depending on your setup:

1) Change `height: 100%` to a fixed value, like `height: 75px`. This will get rid of this issue, but may require some more CSS to properly style the header.

2) If you don't have any clickable items in your header, you could add `pointer-events: none;`. This will make the element 'invisible' to clicks, so your content would work, but nothing in the header would  be clickable (probably not ideal).